# HP-UX: How to know if password was ever established?

Tags: linux, hp-ux

In Linux systems, for a user 
1) if the password was ever established, but the account is locked, then its shows in /etc/shadow file something like:

```
<account>:!!<hashed password>:....
```

2) if the password was never established, it will show something like:

```
<account>:!!:.....
```

However in HP-UX, for both the above situations, it only shows like:

```
<account>:*:....
```

Is there a way in HP-UX that we can find out whether a password was ever established for an account or not.
I did try to google and on hp-forums, but could not find any answer.

Answer (score 2):

According to [No /etc/shadow file found - why is '*' present](http://community.hpe.com/t5/System-Administration/no-etc-shadow-file/td-p/4091188) , it seems that the actual passwords can be in a separate database (where it mentions `/tcb`):

> yes, if you have not activated the Trusted mode the passwords are encrypted into the `/etc/passwd` file. With trusted mode, the passwords and settings are separated in a database under the `/tcb` directory. If you want to convert to trusted mode you can do it by executing `/usr/lbin/tsconvert` or through SAM too.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but i could not find a /tcb directory on our hp-ux box(B.11.23). Is there any other way to find a clear cut answer to whether the password was ever established or not - we don't need to know the actual password, just whether it was ever established (or it was a case where user was created, but no password set)